# zip function doesn't work with initially empty lists

Tags: python

I have a function in a class. In this function, I use zip to combine timestamp and logfile together, then sort timestamp. after sorting, unzip it to get a new logfile sequence according to sorted timestamp.

But I got `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)`.
This code works in vscode debug mode when I initiate 'iniTimestamp' with some value, for example `iniTimestamp = [1,]`.
Can anyone explain why zip doesn't work with initial empty list?
How to make it work?

The input is `self.DATHDF` and `self.sensor`. As the code shown below, in the real program, to read `HDF` files, I use `os.walk` to generate the `self.DATHDF`.

```
logfile1 = h5py.File('../data/sensor1_log1.hdf5',  'r')
logfile2 = h5py.File('../data/sensor1_log2.hdf5',  'r')
logfile3 = h5py.File('../data/sensor1_log3.hdf5',  'r')
logfile4 = h5py.File('../data/sensor2_log1.hdf5',  'r')
logfile5 = h5py.File('../data/sensor2_log2.hdf5',  'r')
logfile6 = h5py.File('../data/sensor2_log3.hdf5',  'r')

self.DATHDF = {
    'sensor1': [logfile1,logfile2,logfile3],
    'sensor2': [logfile4,logfile5,logfile6],
}

self.sensor =['sensor1','sensor2']
```

```
    def sortfile(self):
        '''
        read first element of timestampe from each log file and sort log files according to their initial timestamp
        '''
        self.seqDATHDF ={}
        for s in self.sensor:
            # sort out log files according to measurement timestamp
            iniTimestamp = [] # here it doesn't work with empty initialization of the variable. 
            for log in  self.DATHDF[s]:
                iniTimestamp.append(log['TimeStamp'][0].tolist())
            iniTimestamp = np.asarray(iniTimestamp)
            tmp = sorted(zip(iniTimestamp.flatten().tolist(),self.DATHDF[s]))
            _,self.seqDATHDF[s] = list(zip(*tmp))
```

Here is the error report.

```
 _,self.seqDATHDF[s] = list(zip(*tmp))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Based on this, I just tried to modify 'tmp', and both of them worked.

```
tmp = sorted(zip([1,2,3],[1,2,3]))
#or
iniTimestamp[1,] # initiate this with a value
tmp = sorted(zip(iniTimestamp,iniTimestamp))
```

Comment: What are your inputs to this function? Please see these guidelines on how to make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: what line does raise the error ? Also print the variale between each line to ensure it is what you think

Comment: I added the input and error report

Comment: What should an empty list unpack to? That is, what do you want something like `a, b = []` to be? Because that is essentially your problem. Python has no solution for that, so it raise an exception. It's not that `tmp` is empty: the problem is that you try and assign something that might be empty to two variables.

Comment: so why this code works in VScode debug mode?

Comment: You have to ask VSCode. Does it work on the Python command line for you? That's a better measure.

Comment: You can use a hack/work-around: `_,self.seqDATHDF[s] = list(zip(*tmp)) or [(), ()]`. Since an empty list equates to False, the second half of that expression will be used, which unpacks to two empty tuples.

Comment: @9769953 you are right, when running in terminal, the self.DATHDF is empty....

Comment: it is empty because I used linux path format in windows OS

Comment: Python does tend to translate Linux path (i.e., forward slashes) to Windows path styles (backslashes), so that shouldn't make a difference